# Windows tablet iball

Tags: bios, reset

I have an iball windows tablet.i accidentally disable usb 3.0 from the bios and now it wont detect the keyboard anymore or any usb devices please help.and i cant get into the bios anymore since it wont detect the keyboard.

Comment: which version of windows is on the device?

Comment: Windows 10  is the os

Answer (score 0):

Most tablets or hand-held devices supply a way of getting into the BIOS by
holding some button(s) during the boot.

I can't find any information about IBall tablets, as the available information is
mostly marketing hype. You could maybe phone the Support line to ask if such
a method exists.

For example, for the Surface Pro the method is as follows :

- Shut down your Surface.
- Press and hold the Volume Up button on your Surface, then press and release the Power button.
- When you see the Surface logo screen appear, release the Volume Up button. The Surface UEFI screen will appear in a few seconds.

I have seen other devices where keeping on holding the Power button when booting
gets one into the BIOS.

If you succeed on getting into the BIOS, undo your change of the
USB3 settings.
If you can't find it, there is perhaps a Reset BIOS or similar button somewhere
in the BIOS menus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes now i can get into the bios but i cant navigate through it cause no keyboard.its stuck on the the home screen of the bios.this sucks so close yet so far.

Comment: On the Surface Pro the BIOS supports touch. On other tablets I have seen, the volume keys and others are used for navigation without keyboard.